# using javascript to change style.color of a <label> element FAILS

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following code works in FF but not in IE9:

```
     // turn on the 'image file upload' field and its label
    document.getElementById('itemImageId').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('labelForImageUploadID').style.color = "black";
```

Here is the HTML with the label and the file input:

```
    <label for="itemImageId" style="color: silver" id="labelForImageUploadID">Item image
            (select to change the item's current image)</label>
    <input type="file" size="100px" id="itemImageId" disabled="disabled"
                     name="theFileUpload"></input>
```

** EDIT **  The above label and file upload tags are nested inside the following **div** -- I added this so you can see how the mouse click is handled.  The **handleRowClick()** function has the above Javascript code that tries to turn the text black:

```
      <div class="itemlistRowContainer" id="topmostDiv_ID" onclick="handleRowClick(this);"
         onmouseover="handleMouseOver(this);" onmouseout="handleMouseOut(this);"
         ondblclick="handleDblClick(this);">
```

So when this label first appears on the page, its color is correct -- it is silver due to the inline color style.

Then the Javascript code above executes on a mouse click.

In Firefox, the Javascript code turns the label text to black, and enables the file upload control.

However in IE9 the label's text stays gray.

Does IE9 not support **style.color = "somecolor"**  to dynamically control colors of the **label** tag?

I've looked at a few other posts, and the only quirk I found was that if you have enabling/disabling 
happening dynamically, to make sure the tag is ENABLED in IE9 before you try to change its color.

That's not a factor here as the code never disables the **label** tag.

It's not just this one **label** tag either -- all the **label** tags on the page fail to 
turn black but ONLY in IE9 -- in FF everything works.

Is there a 'gotcha' or a trick I'm missing?

Comment: How are you binding the click event?

Comment: Sorry for taking awhile -- I added the mouse click handler to my code above.

Comment: seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/pP3dd/ .  There may be something else going on in the page.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this.

The original problem was -- my **label** tags would not redraw/refresh in IE when I changed their text color from silver to black -- this code below failed but ONLY in Internet Explorer -- the code below worked FINE in Firefox etc.:

```
   // turn on the 'image file upload' label
document.getElementById('labelForImageUploadID').style.color = "black";
```

**SYMPTOMS AND CLUES**

Did I know that the above code was, in fact, changing the text of the **label** to black in IE?
Yes.  But to see the text color change on the **label** tags on my page after the above code executed, I had to either:

- resize the IE browser window -- and BAM the **label** text changed to black
- or doubleclick in an empty area of the IE browser window -- same effect, the **label** text would then show the effects of the above code, the text would turn black.

So I knew the color change to black was working in the code, and I learned that the problem "must be that the IE9 browser window is not refreshing the **label** tag after the color change."

Here are a couple things I tried that had no effect:

- made 'hasLayout' true by adding *zoom:1* to the style of the **label** and to its parent **div**
- added a fixed pixel width to the **label** and to its parent **div**

These 2 attempts were based on what I read **[HERE](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1354-The-Power-Of-ZOOM-Fixing-CSS-Issues-In-Internet-Explorer.htm)**

Those things did not help.  Besides, I already had 'display:inline-block' for the **label**'s parent **div**
which also (supposedly) forces 'hasLayout' for IE issues.

**HERE IS THE SOLUTION**

```
    // THIS DID NOT WORK IN IE BUT WAS FINE IN Firefox:
       // document.getElementById('labelForImageUploadID').style.color = "black";

    // THIS WORKS IN IE and IN FIREFOX
    var imageUploadLabel = document.getElementById('labelForImageUploadID');
    imageUploadLabel.style.color = "black";
    imageUploadLabel.style.display = "none";
    imageUploadLabel.style.display = "inline-block"
```

What a kludgy piece of code.

I'm sure there's probably a more elegant way (I thought *hasLayout*,
*zoom:1*, etc. would work but for me no such luck).

At the time I wrote my solution here, no one had (yet) chimed in with a more elegant way to force IE to redraw my **label** tags when I change their text color -- maybe after seeing my workaround here someone will provide a more elegant way to force
IE to redraw **label** tags when their text color changes.

ONE THING I will add:  maybe my DOCTYPE is causing this problem -- chime in if you think it is.  This is the DOCTYPE I use on my pages:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 3):

The code works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/HKhjs/

My assumption is you're relying on `addEventlistener()` only which is merely JavaScript. IE uses it's own flavor called JScript which uses `attachEvent`.

```
object.attachEvent(event, callback)
```

Comment: I added the 'onclick()' handler to my code above -- I don't use addEventListener() at least not to my knowledge.  I hate IE.

Comment: to make sure my **style.color = "black"** line of code was being reached upon a mouse click -- I put an alert() *right after* that line of code.  AND NOW SUDDENLY after dismissing the alert() box the black text turned on when the focus switched back to the IE window.  I removed the alert() call -- and the text again would not change to black although I now know the line of code is executing.  SO I RESIZED THE IE WINDOW.  And the text turned black!!!  IE is somehow not refreshing the window without manually resizing it, or putting in an alert() call that switches focus for a second then back.

Comment: Okay pretty sure I've found an IE9 bug.  After my **style.color = "black"** line of code executes -- and the text is still gray -- if I simply double-click on any white area of the IE9 browser window -- the black text turns on.  Anyone hear of a 'not refreshing browser' bug with IE9?